# Keras loss and metrics values do not match with same function in each

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am using keras with a custom loss function like below:

```
def custom_fn(y_true, y_pred):
   # changing y_true, y_pred values systematically
   return mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred)
```

Then I am calling `model.compile(loss=custom_fn)` and `model.fit(X, y,..validation_data=(X_val, y_val)..)`

Keras is then saving `loss` and `val_loss` in model history. As a sanity check, when the model finishes training, I am using `model.predict(X_val)` so I can calculate validation loss manually with my `custom_fn` using the trained model.

I am saving the model with the best epoch using this callback:

```
callbacks.append(ModelCheckpoint(path, save_best_only=True, monitor='val_loss', mode='min'))
```

so after calculating this, the validation loss should match keras' `val_loss` value of the best epoch. But this is not happening.

As another attempt to figure this issue out, I am also doing this:

```
    model.compile(loss=custom_fn, metrics=[custom_fn])
```

**And to my surprise, `val_loss` and `val_custom_fn` do not match (neither `loss` or `loss_custom_fn` for that matter).**

This is really strange, my `custom_fn` is essentially keras' built in `mape` with the `y_true` and `y_pred` slightly manipulated. what is going on here?

**PS**: the layers I am using are `LSTM` layers and a final `Dense` layer. But I think this information is not relevant to the problem. I am also using regularisation as hyperparameter but not dropout.

### Update

Even removing `custom_fn` and using keras' built in `mape` as a loss function and metric like so:

```
model.compile(loss='mape', metrics=['mape'])
```

and for simplicity, removing `ModelCheckpoint` callback is having the same effect; **`val_loss` and `val_mape` for each epoch are not equivalent**. This is extremely strange to me. I am either missing something or there is a bug in Keras code..the former might be more realistic.

Comment: could u please report also the callback method u used to save the best model?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani Just included that now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [blog post](https://challengeenthusiast.com/2018/08/16/validation-loss-contamination-by-regularization-term-in-keras/) suggests that keras adds any regularisation used in the training when calculating the validation loss. And obviously, when calculating the metric of choice no regularisation is applied. This is why it occurs with any loss function of choice as stated in the question.

This is something I could not find any documentation on from Keras. However, it seems to hold up since when I remove all regularisation hyperparameters, the `val_loss` and `val_custom_fn` match exactly in each epoch.

An easy workaround is to either use the `custom_fn` as a metric and save the best model based on the metric (`val_custom_fn`) than on the `val_loss`. Or else Loop through each epoch manually and calculate the correct `val_loss` manually after training each epoch. The latter seems to make more sense since there is no reason to include `custom_fn` both as a metric and as a loss function.

If anyone can find any evidence of this in the Keras documentation that would be helpful.